# Condition on linear transformations to be non-singular

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $T$ be a linear transformation over a linear vector space $L$. For $T$ to be non-singular, it has to be one-to-one and onto i.e. a bijection. Since a linear transformation is a homomorphism of the first space onto the second space, does this imply that the $T$ is non-singular only when it is an isomorphism on $L$?

It would be helpful if someone explains in simple mathematical terms, as much as possible, as I am not a  student of Mathematics.

Comment: The terms "isomorphism" and "bijection" are usually used only when the co-domain is explicitly mentioned, otherwise every injective function could be seen as a bijection, and although you could argue for this classification from the set theoretic definition of a function, it is useful to distinguish injections from bijections by explicitly stating the co-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism by definition.

Comment: Not by definition

Comment: "Not by definition" is a comment that should be properly justified as time has been taken to write it, because it seems you are familiar with the correct definition. There are textbooks that define a bijective linear transformation between vector spaces as an isomorphism. If the author of this response received this definition, then what they are saying is correct. In the other response, you make a more assertive comment "should not be considered a definition," but you also do not indicate why. I find these kinds of comments inappropriate for a mathematics forum. @AnneBauval

Comment: @A.P. This comment was indeed echoing the more precise one below the other answer. The link I gave in point 3 of my own answer justifies them. I hope all this helps the OP, who was asking for a logical relationship between the 2 notions (bijection and isomorphism) in the linear context. If the OP or Marc-André asks for details, I will be happy to help, as always.

Comment: Hello Anne! I am using the definition from Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra (3rd edition), where on p.345 they define a $R$-module isomorphism as a $R$-module homomorphism that is both injective and surjective. I didn't remember or know what a non-singular linear transformation was so I went by what the OP wrote, "i.e. a bijection".

Answer (score 2):

Consider more generally a linear map $T:V\to W.$

1. $T$ is non-singular iff it is one-to-one. This implies $\dim V\le\dim W.$
2. When $\dim V=\dim W<\infty,$ $T$ is one-to-one iff it is onto.
3. When $T$ is bijective, its inverse is linear hence $T$ is an [isomorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism).

Answer (score 0):

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation. Assuming $V$ and $W$ both to be finite-dimensional, every non-singular linear transformation $T$ is an isomorphism. After all, an isomorphism of vector spaces is a bijective linear transformation. In fact, if dim$V=$dim$W$, then $V\cong W$.

Comment: It is false that "Assuming $V$ and $W$ both to be finite-dimensional, every non-singular linear transformation $T$ is an isomorphism." You must of course assume moreover $\dim V\ge\dim W.$

Comment: "an isomorphism of vector spaces is a bijective linear transformation" should not be considered as a definition but as a theorem.

Comment: @AnneBauval: with reference a your first comment "... non-singular linear transformation $T$ is an isomorphim..." . Do you have any counterexample specific? Fortunately, in mathematics we have counterexamples.

Comment: @A.P. Didn't you find any? I gave a big hint, though! ;-)

Comment: @AnneBauval What is your definition of "singular"?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I found the same definition on many pages by googling "singular linear transformation". Here is a book giving also the same answer https://books.google.fr/books?id=aqruCh5Hb2cC&pg=PA341 a linear map is singular if its kernel (=null space) is $\supsetneq\{0\}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I cannot see the book at that link.  Google is offering me no preview.  Can you just give your definition?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Done. But if you google on your own like I did, you will certainly find similar pages.

Comment: Okay, thanks to @AkivaWeinberger, I have seen the page in question.  The definition there is that an operator is non-singular if it has a trivial kernel.  This is not the usual definition taught in most elementary linear algebra classes---in those classes, a non-singular matrix is a *square* matrix with nonzero determinant (i.e. a *square* matrix with trivial kernel).

Comment: "But if you google on your own like I did, you will certainly find similar pages"  Please don't be condescending.  The fundamental problem here is that we are using different definitions.  Telling someone to Google in order to find the definition you are using is *not* helpful.

Comment: I am sorry if I seemed condescending to you. I did my best possible to help. I couldn't find another method 
 @XanderHenderson Do you want me to copy-paste the reference of that book? And of some more books or pdf's?

Comment: Anyway the OP give the version of non-singular: "For $T$ to be non-singular, it has to be one-to-one and onto i.e. a bijection" which seems to differ then with the one being used here. Hence why I requested the example. @AnneBauval